Interior chimney stone veneer mortar cleanup
I have an exterior brick chimney that has had water infiltration.  Hopefully that has been fixed.
Water would work it's way down inside, and they hit the interior stone veneer system, and come out through the mortar.  This causes discoloration, efflorescence and flaking.   I'm using a shop vac to vacuum up all the loose bits.   There are white streaks on some stone, so I'm going to have to use some water and brush and sponge that off.
I'm considering what to do after that.  I don't think enough has come off to be worth repointing.  Though I'm considering if makes sense to seal the surface with some sort of sealant to keep the loose surface from continuing to just flake off.  What kind of material would work or application would be appropriate. (paint brush or spray)   This is a ~12 ft high by 6 ft wide chimney



